# PlayBook file browser

Tags: apache-flex, blackberry-playbook

I'm developing an application for the Blackberry Playbook using Flash Burrito 4.5 and Flex.
I'd like to create a file browser to allow users to load images from the local system into the application.
I followed this example
http://techblog.floorplanner.com/2009/05/04/load-modify-and-save-local-images-with-flash-player-10/
When I click on the Load Image button in the simulator however, the file browser pops up but tells me that "no file was found with the specified filter", even though I don't specify any filter or even if I specify a *.* filter.
Have you got any idea of what the problem might be?

Thanks in advance

Comment: You're going to have to post your code.  Did you try to use FileReference.browse()? Did that work at all?

Answer (score 0):

That tutorial seems a bit outdated for what you're trying to do. I'd recommend using the File class.

Start with something like:

```
var file:File = File.desktopDirectory;
```

Allow the user to navigate to the file they're looking for and then load the image using the file.nativePath.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at that Application from Duane [MobileFileBrowser](http://technoracle.blogspot.com/2010/12/mobile-development-with-flash-builder.html)